# $H_2$, its might and Type III error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

I've recently found myself wondering about the following thing in hypothesis testing:

We can test some *null hypothesis* $H_0$ and reject it based on its p-value. This is akin to accepting (*shreek!!!*) the *complementary hypothesis* $\neg H_0$. For instance, in a two-sided t-test, rejecting equality $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ means accepting inequality $(\neg H_0):\mu_1\neq\mu_2$. We can explicitly make $\neg H_0$ an *alternative hypothesis*  $H_1$ and define its power $1-\beta$.

|  | $H_0$ | $H_1$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Keep $H_0$ | $1-\alpha$ | Type II error probability $\beta$ |
| Reject $H_0$ | Type I error probability $\alpha$ | power $1-\beta$ |

Of course, we teach our students to shy away from the phrasing of "accepting $H_1$" because $H_1$ can be defined in other ways than a complementary hypothesis, as long as $H_0$ and $H_1$ are mutually exclusive. That is, we require $H_0 \wedge H_1 \equiv F$, but not $H_1 \equiv \neg H_0$. In the latter case, rejecting $H_0$ does not automatically imply $H_1$, such as in the Jonckheere-Terpstra test, where

$H_0: \theta_1=\theta_2=\theta_3=\dots$

$H_1: (\theta_1\leq\theta_2\leq\theta_3\leq\dots) \wedge \exists i<j: \theta_i<\theta_j$

Such tests are of course designed to have high power for a specific $H_1$ scenario we're interested in.

This leaves a *residual hypothesis* $H_2 := \neg (H_0 \vee H_1) $, which we usually don't care about. For Jonckhere-Terpstra for instance, this would be

$H_2: \exists i<j: \theta_i>\theta_j$

We could extend the table above to include $H_2$:

|  | $H_0$ | $H_1$ | $H_2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Keep $H_0$ | $1-\alpha$ | Type II error probability $\beta$ | Type III error probability $\gamma$ |
| Reject $H_0$ | Type I error probability $\alpha$ | power $1-\beta$ | might $1-\gamma$ |

I choose the terms "residual hypothesis", "$\gamma$" and "might" (as a synonym to "power" and because the test *might or might not* reject $H_0$ under $H_2$, we just don't care), as I have never seen them in the wild, and I was wondering:

1. Is there an established terminology for these concepts?
2. Is there any theoretical treatment of the *might* of a test, and any relationship to the power (lower/upper bounds? etc.)
3. Is there any good treatment of these concepts in the introductory teaching literature?

I know there is some work in this direction (related: [Is a Type III statistical error just a subset of Type I or II error?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405427/is-a-type-iii-statistical-error-just-a-subset-of-type-i-or-ii-error), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_III_error) such as Gelman's Type S and M errors, though they seem to be only for specific cases (such direction of effect in one-sided tests), rather than a general residual hypothesis $H_2$.

Comment: $H_2$ is ill-defined because it's not covered by the model.  In particular, probability itself is not meaningful for a Type III error unless you extend your model to a hierarchical one.

Comment: I do not quite get what you are saying. In the simple case of a one-sided t-test with $H_1:\mu_1<\mu_2$, the $H_2: \mu_1 > \mu_2$ is well-defined and might hold, and we might reject $H_0$ in that case, unlikely as it may be.

Comment: In fact, there can be distributions not in $H_0$ or $H_1$ about which we may care very much. For example we may use a t-test for testing the $H_0$ that a normal mean $\mu=0$ against $\mu\neq0$, but in fact data are not precisely normally distributed (they never are), and we're still interested in if their mean is 0 or not. On the other hand, as in your example, there may be distributions we don't care much about, and it's probably worthwhile to distinguish these cases.

Comment: In case of $H_2$ being true it is far from trivial and may depend on details of the application what even constitutes an "error", i.e., a "correct" or "incorrect" decision of the test. Also the class of distributions not being in $H_0$ and $H_1$ is usually staggeringly large, and any comprehensive summary of the properties of a test in case of $H_2$ may be hard or impossible to obtain (unless you constrain yourself to very specific $H_2$-members).